# LUT as Distributed RAM

Tags: fpga, xilinx

Im not sure in how the Distributed RAM is implemented using LUTs. Would the inputs be used for both address, control write/read and data signals?

[image]

Comment: The logic block is either configured as ram OR a LUT.

Comment: Depends on the FPGA mfg and device family. For most newish Xilinx parts, see Kartman's comment. Or your FPGA's documentation.

Answer (score 3):

A LUT is a dual-port SRAM. It has a read port (address in, data out), which is how you use it for logic. But it also has a write port (address in, write enable in, data in), which is how the FPGA's start-up logic transfers data from the nonvolatile configuration memory into the SRAM following power-up.

It just takes one more configuration bit to make the LUT usable as distributed RAM, and that bit controls a multiplexer for the write port. That multiplexer's second input is available to the user logic, so now you can both write to and read from the SRAM.

Comment: Thanks but how can you use a 6input LUT as Distributed RAM? Are the inputs broken into data signals and control signasl?

Comment: The original 6 inputs are the address bus for the read port. There are additional inputs for the write port (6 address, 1 data in, 1 write enable) that become available when the mux is activated.

Comment: Got it thank you

Comment: @YogiBear I think it would be appropriate to accept Dave's answer if it answered your question!